# mysql_fetch_array is getting one value on my query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to print a list of data from a mysql table, and then i want to print data from another table related to the first table. The first list is okay, but the second is only printing the last row of the data.

```
$queryfunc=mysql_query("select * from title");
foreach ($func as $funcc){
$iddd=$funcc[0];
$funcao=$funcc[1];
echo "<li class='has-sub'><a><span>" .$funcao. "</span></a>";
```

At this point, i have a full list of the data from the first table. I need to take the ID of a row of the first list, and print the following with data related to that ID:

```
$newq=mysql_query("select nome from utilizadores where title=$iddd");
$namm=array();
while ($rowww=mysql_fetch_array($newq)) $namm[]=$rowww;
foreach ($namm as $nomi){
$nee=$nomi[0];
echo "<ul><a href='php/curriculo.php?nomeut=$nomes' target=_blank>" .$nee. "</a></ul>";
    }
}
```

Here, it is only printing the last result from the table.

Thanks

Comment: If this is new code, you *really* shouldn't be using `mysql_query`. `$iddd` doesn't appear to be [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and is probably a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: 1. `mysql_query` requires you to pass the connection to it as an argument. 2. `mysql_*` is deprecated! STOP USING IT 3. Run your query directly, and see what results you're dealing with. 4. What manner of weird variable names are you using???

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `mysql_query` doesn't actually require an explicit connection resource (it's lazy and will use the last opened connection). That's why so many people get confused by `mysqli_query`, etc, which all require the connection resource.

Comment: The result i am dealing with is "select nome from utilizadores where title=22". This query is okay. - I've tested in phpmyadmin, it is printing me 3 results. Only the last one is showing in php

Comment: You first query doesn't appear to have any fetch associated with it (ie to match the other loop you appear to be missing `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($queryfunc)) $func[]=$row;` ).

Comment: Do you really need to fetch all the record in one array before processing them? It seems you could get rid of the first loop and process each `$rowww` directly.

Comment: Regarding the line: while ($rowww=mysql_fetch_array($newq)) $namm[]=$rowww; -- This gets each successive row and places it into the same $namm[], overlaying what ever was already in $namm[], so, when that while loop exits, only the last row is in the $namm[] array.